# How to override default destructor for std::atomic classes

Tags: c++, c++11, destructor, atomic

I defined a class named `Node` and I declare the following variable using `std::atomic`:

```
 atomic<Node *> head(new Node());
```

The `Node` pointer contained within will be `deleted` once the atomic class itself is destructed, however I want the pointer to be deleted elsewhere.

I am using MinGW and I checked the GCC source code, it does use the default destructor.

How can I override the default destructor for atomic class?

Comment: _"The Node pointer contained within will be deleted once the atomic class itself is destructed"_ It won't be deleted. Where did you get that from?

Comment: You can use for example std::shared_ptr<Node> to delete memory pointed by your pointer. It allows you to customise destruction.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/memory/shared_ptr/~shared_ptr/

Comment: [`std::shared_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr)? Also, can you please elaborate on the *actual* problem you want to solve with this "solution" you want help with ([related reading about the XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/))?

Comment: *will be `deleted`* Citation needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The destructor for `atomic<Node*>` does not delete the pointee, so there is nothing you need to do.